# Where are MLE equations such as $\sum_{i=1}^n \bigg(y_i - \frac{e^{x_i^T \beta}}{1+e^{x_i^T \beta}} \bigg)x_{ij}=0$ derived?

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Where are MLE equations such as $$\sum_{i=1}^n \bigg(y_i - \frac{e^{x_i^T \beta}}{1+e^{x_i^T \beta}} \bigg)x_{ij}=0$$ for $Y_i \text{~} Bin(1, \pi_i)$ derived?

Comment: @whuber Are you sure? I don't see my kind of equation there.

Comment: Try reading the answer.  It has plenty of equations.